# Remove the filter arrows from the first row in a themed SpreadJS table

Tags: angular, spreadjs

I am working with SpreadJS for the first time, and am busy wrapping my head around how the table styling works. I am theming to apply styles over the entire table, but there is a funny thing happening when I do so.

Whenever I apply a theme, whether it is a custom or predefined theme, the first row of the table gets these arrows that look like a filter control. Please see the images below for clarification.

Without theme:

[image]

With theme:

[image]

I apply my theme as follows:

```
let rowCount = activeSheet.getRowCount();
let colCount = activeSheet.getColumnCount();
activeSheet.tables.add("Table1", 0, 0, rowCount, colCount, GC.Spread.Sheets.Tables.TableThemes.light1);
```

Does anyone have any advice to prevent the first row from having these filter arrows applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a member of GrapeCity’s technical engagement team. You can use SpreadJS’s [filterButtonVisible method](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/SpreadJS%7EGC.Spread.Sheets.Tables.Table.html#:%7E:text=in%20binding%20case.%20%C2%A0-,filterButtonVisible,-Gets%20or%20sets) to set whether the table column’s filter button should be displayed. You would apply this like so:

```
let rowCount = activeSheet.getRowCount();
let colCount = activeSheet.getColumnCount();
var table = activeSheet.tables.add("Table1", 0, 0, rowCount, colCount, GC.Spread.Sheets.Tables.TableThemes.light1);
// removes table filters
table.filterButtonVisible(false);
```

Here is a link to a sample showing this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sjs-angular-table-remove-filters-s1h8o?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:1726-1727